# Why the mixed effect model and the meta-analysis model generate different results given the dependent variable is uncorrelated?

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, clinical-trials

I have a data that looks like the following:

```
  ID Male Diabetes Renal failure Hepatic disease Coronary artery disease Cancer COPD
1  1    1        1             0               0                       0      0    0
2  2    1        1             0               1                       0      0    0
3  3    0        0             0               0                       0      0    0
4  4    0        0             0               0                       0      0    0
5  5    1        0             0               0                       0      0    1
6  6    1        0             0               0                       0      0    0
  Immunodeficiency Sepsis ARDS due to pneumonia Vasopressors Neuromuscular blockers
1                0      1                     1            1                      1
2                1      1                     1            1                      0
3                0      0                     0            0                      1
4                0      0                     1            1                      1
5                0      1                     1            1                      0
6                0      1                     0            1                      1
  Renal-replacement therapy Glucocorticoids SOFA score SAPS II Body-mass index Age treatment
1                         0               0         12      57              27  73         1
2                         0               0          9      30              30  71         1
3                         0               0          9      26              32  56         1
4                         0               0         13      67              22  76         1
5                         0               0         18      37              39  57         1
6                         0               0          7      57              28  43         1
```

From `Diabetes` to `Glucocorticoid` are baseline characteristics of a patient. I saw a paper recently using meta-analysis like analysis to assess the imbalance of baseline characteristics among treatment group and control group. The idea is to treat the each of these baseline disease like a study in meta-analysis and run the meta-analysis. The odds ratio in this case is the odds of having the one characteristic against not having them among treatment group and control group. However it seems to me the method is not very convincing because what if these baseline characteristics are correlated. Say if Diabetes are strongly correlated to the renal failure, it doesn't make any sense to take average of both.

The meta-analysis results will generate an odds ratio of 1.51.

However, I tried to use the mixed effect model to run the analysis by transforming the data into long format, so each ID will have repetitive observations, and all these baseline characteristics will be coded as either 1 or 0 as a single column like an outcome, the data format looks like the following:

```
> head(db1_long[,c(1,2,7,9,10)])
  ID Male treatment binary_value effect
1  1    1         1            1      1
2  1    1         1            0      0
3  1    1         1            0      0
4  1    1         1            0      0
5  1    1         1            0      0
6  1    1         1            0      0
```

Where the binary_value is either 1 or 0, the first row corresponds to whether diabetes equals 0, the second is the Ranel failure, etc. The last column indicates whether the characteristics has a positive effect or negative effect on the outcome through treatment (sadly, I don't have data on the outcome of the treatment)

The results from the mixed effect model look like the following:

```
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula:          binary_value ~ treatment + (1 | ID) + (1 | effect)
Data: db1_long

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7363.1   7389.9  -3677.6   7355.1     6054 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 ID     (Intercept) 1.940e-09 4.404e-05
 effect (Intercept) 3.783e-01 6.151e-01
Number of obs: 6058, groups:  ID, 466; effect, 2

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -0.44339    0.43698  -1.015    0.310  
treatment    0.11879    0.05633   2.109    0.035 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Even if I took the exponential of the estimates from the treatment, the result estimated odds are `1.12` which is way smaller than the estimate from the meta-analysis. However, in this case, all these baseline characteristics are uncorrelated ( the correlation matrix has approximately 0 for all the off-diagonal entries).

I am puzzled by the disparity between the two methods given that the covariates are actually uncorrelated. Why is this the case? Can anyone explain it both intuitively and also use concrete mathematical formulas behind each model?